# How to maximize a window programmably in X Window?

Tags: scripting, x11, window-management

I'm wondering if there is any commands or programs to make some window maximized in X Window? For example, what I imagine is something like this

```
xmaximize -window *window_id*
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using `wmctrl`.

#### Example

Get your window's ID.

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x02a00004  0 grinchy saml@grinchy:~
0x0620004f  0 grinchy [gnome] Bash command for Maximizing and Unmaximizing windows in gnome? - Google Chrome
```

Then toggle window ID `0x0620004f`, like so.

```
$ wmctrl -i -r 0x0620004f -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

Comment: I'll just note that this requires a window manager that supports EWMH/NetWM, which is most likely the case, but something that should be checked if this doesn't work.

Comment: @casey Thanks for this information. Wondering where did you get this such that I can figure out how to check it.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simpler way, just put this code in a script, and set executable with a keyboard shortcut. Works for me.

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

Comment: Can this be automatised for specific applications?